# same backreference in subpatterns, php pcre regexp

Tags: php, regex

I found this at

http://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.subpatterns.php

(?|(Sat)ur|(Sun))day

this mean (Sat) and Sun will be matched at same order

but When I test with regexbuddy it occurr a error 
abt syntax
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work fine with a recent version of PCRE - did you make sure to switch regexbuddy into PCRE mode?

You'll need a pretty recent version too. My PHP 5.2.6 install is too old (PCRE 6.6 2006-02-06), while PHP 5.2.17 (8.02 2010-03-19) is fine.

This test PHP program:

```
$a = "it is Sunday tomorrow";
preg_match('/(?|(Sat)ur|(Sun))day/', $a, $m);
print_r($m);
```

Outputs this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Sunday
    [1] => Sun
)
```

If your version of PCRE is too old, you'll get this error:

```
 Compilation failed: unrecognized character after (? at offset 2
```